# Impossible to drop partition table and format EFI partition. Immutable partition table?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I am trying to format my computer's entire hard disk, but it does not work due to the EFI partition. I tried the following approaches:

1. **Windows 10 installation** - when i am trying to delete a partition, nothing happens. Format works for all disk but EFI
2. **Diskpart** - enter to the disc, typed CLEAN, then list partiton (empty) after restart those were still present.
3. **Ubuntu** - go to ubuntu, used fdisk (screen attached), after another enter to fdisk the partition was still there. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqRgx.png)
4. **Ubuntu** - `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/mydisk ...` <- after this finished, partition still was present.

What's wrong with the approaches I've tried? Is it possible that partition table is immutable? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu from a live session or in a dual boot?

Comment: Is `mmcblk0` an SD card, or is it internal eMMC memory?

Comment: Ubuntu as bootable pendrive. it looks like sd card as disk or not sure, is any of these explain behaviour? Linux UI said that this is sd card

Comment: In a live session you should be able to do anything you want provided the no partition oif the said drive is mounted (it shouldn't be unless you clicked on it in the file manager). But there's really no need to delete the EFI partition as it is needed anyway. And in Ubuntu you can use GParted, a GUI tool and with that create a new partition table which will automatically blank the whole drive.